# Smarty Multiple Pages (each tpl has one php)

Tags: php, smarty

Sup guys.

I wan't to make a website with Smarty. The Problem I have is that I can't found a good Tutorial for multiple pages.

I want for each .tpl a .php like for index.tpl i have index.php, for page1.tpl I have page1.php etc.

One guy said to me that I have to create a "pager" / "kernel" doing that.
Sad that I am not much familar with php to create a "pager" / "kernel".

So Im asking you guys, how can I make this? I found another question here, where the pages are in a switch. But I don't know how the rest of the code will be.

I just want my .tpl files where I put HTML Code and Smarty code. And in the php file of the .tpl is the php code for functions, variables etc. only available for the .tpl site.

My current structur is

```
- cache
- configs
- libs
   - (Smarty libs)
- templates
    - index.tpl
    - page1.tpl
- templates_c
- index.php
- page1.php
```

I don't have any code because after all that Tutorials I read I am very confused now. My brain is like 1945.

Comment: What's *wrong* with your current solution of `index.tpl` and `page1.tpl`? That should work fine, but you should consider using something more modern than Smarty, like Laravel.

Comment: You dont have to create a kernel, you can just use something Like [Silex](https://silex.symfony.com/), or [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/). If you use Silex id urge you to go with Twig over Smarty though

Comment: I found an example on github which doesn't work. Only index.tpl works but the page tpl's aren't working.